# How to properly animate UIButton press/release when there's a quick tap?

Tags: ios, swift

I'd like to animate a `UIButton` when it's pressed/released. It works fine if the user waits a little before releasing the button -- but if the tap is quick, the release animation interrupts the press animation too soon. What is the proper way to do this?

I scale the button on touch down:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {          
    self.btnFoobar.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.5, y: 0.5)
})
```

Then I scale it back on touch up:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, delay: 0.0) {
    self.btnFoobar.transform = .identity
}
```

But if touch up occurs before the touch down animation has finished, it interrupts the animation and it doesn't look right. I thought of using `UIViewPropertyAnimator` to implement a continuous animation but couldn't find anyone else doing that online, so I'm not sure if I should.

A dirty workaround I found is to put a delay on the release animation, but I'm not so happy with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to ensure the touch-up animation isn't run until at least the touch-down animation has had a chance to finish, you can check the timestamp of the two events and adjust the touch-up animation delay as needed.

Here's some working code:

```swift
private var downStart = Date()
private static var duration = 0.1 // changing to 0.5 makes it easier to test

@objc func touchDown(_ button: UIButton) {
    downStart = Date() // Note when the touch-down happens
    UIView.animate(withDuration: Self.duration) {
        button.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    }
}

@objc func touchUp(_ button: UIButton) {
    // Delay the touch-up animation if needed
    let delay = max(downStart.timeIntervalSinceNow + Self.duration, 0.0)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: Self.duration, delay: delay) {
        button.transform = .identity
    }
}
```

The line `let delay = max(downStart.timeIntervalSinceNow + Self.duration, 0.0)` will result in no delay if the touch-up happens more than `duration` seconds after the touch-down event. Otherwise it will be the remaining time needed so the touch-down animation can complete.

Comment: Ok, this is a good approach, thank you